# ASP.Net Web Forms - How to set properties of MasterPage from page and user controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, master-pages

I have two master pages which are used by different content pages.
I want to set master page properties from content page, so that master page can show some changes based on those values. And then I also need to access those master page properties in user controls added in master page to reflect some changes. How to achieve that?

I have found a way how to set master page properties from content page by adding `<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="/Site.master" %>` and then using `**Master.property=value**` but not sure about how to access user control. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a base class form which your master pages inherit from that includes the properties you're looking to store:

```
abstract public class MasterPageBase : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public string Prop1
    {
        get { return "Some Value"; }
    }
}
```

From your UserControl, you can then access the properties as follows:

```
MasterPageBase masterPage = (MasterPageBase)this.Page.Master;
string strTest = masterPage.Prop1; // "Some Value"
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the above answers to work, so here is what worked for me:

You want to reference a master page property from a user control.

Firstly, your master page will have a public property like so :

```
public string BodyClass
{
    set
    {
        this.masterBody.Attributes.Add("class", value);
    }
}
```

Now add a reference to the master page in the user control ASCX file like so :

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Source/MasterPages/Main.master" TagPrefix="MSTR" TagName="MasterPage" %>
```

Then in the code behind (C# in my case) you have this code :

```
Main masterPage = (Main)this.Page.Master;
masterPage.BodyClass = "container";
```

Without the reference to the master page above your user control will not be able to find the master page class.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can access user control defined in your master page in two ways:

By using FindControl method, in order to use this you have to add the server tags for user control in content page too, in .aspx page add this:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/myControl.ascx" TagName="myControl" TagPrefix"uc" %>
```

then in code behind:

```
myControl = (myControl)this.Page.Master.FindControl("userControl_Id");
```

or you can create a public property in your masterpage that returns your usercontrol:

```
public myControl UserControl { get; set; }
```

and in code behind of your content page you can access this user control simply through UserControl property:

```
myControl ctrl = (myControl)this.Page.Master.UserControl;
```

Answer (score 0):

The controls is defined in Master.designer.cs with access modifier "protected." Cut and paste its definition to code-behind (Master.cs) and change the access modifier to "public."
Then you can access the Master Page control as in the answer given by Derek Hunziker:

```
MasterPageBase masterPage = (MasterPageBase)this.Page.Master;
string strTest = masterPage.Prop1; // "Some Value"
```